# jquery not preventing postback, then regrabbing raw data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am capturing credit card info from a basic USB credit card reader. A bloated stream of ASCII data is sent to the text box, which my js parses down to the useful bits. That all works fine.

I have the following chunk of jquery in my ASP.NET app that works perfectly on a different page, but breaks on the page in question. The only difference between the jquery below, and what I have on the other page that works, is the 1st line, the .unbind(). I added that line because it's the only way I could find to get the "change" listener to fire. But it has a side effect: after the change listener fires and the data stream gets scrubbed, somehow a postback occurs, and then the RAW data stream gets plopped into my text box: txtCreditCardNumber.

IMPORTANT: The card swiper seems to be sending a CRLF at the end of the stream, so maybe this is causing the postback. But that's puzzling because even if I enter something manually into the textbox and hit ENTER, no postback occurs.

The other page doesn't auto-postback when the card is swiped. On this page, without the unbind, the change listener never gets called, but with it, I get correct parsing/scrubbing, followed by the the postback, followed by the textbox being populated with the full raw data stream from the card reader.

```
$("#txtCreditCardNumber").unbind("keypress");

$('#txtCreditCardNumber').bind('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.which == 46 || e.which == 8)
        return; // always ignore the DELETE and BACKSPACE keys

    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var ccRawData = $(element).val();
        ccNumber = getCCNumberFromRawData(ccRawData);
        ccExpYear = getCCExpYearFromRawData(ccRawData);
        ccExpMonth = getCCExpMonthFromRawData(ccRawData, false);
        ccNameOnCard = getCCNameOnCardFromRawData(ccRawData);

        if (ccExpMonth.length == 1)
            ccExpMonth = "0" + ccExpMonth;

        $('#txtCreditCardNumber').val(ccNumber);
        $('#txtCCExpirationDate').val(ccExpMonth + "" + ccExpYear);
        //$('#ccEmbeddedName').html(ccNameOnCard);
        $("#txtCreditCardNumber").attr('maxlength', '16');
    }, 0);
    return false;
});
```

And here is the ASP.NET textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCreditCardNumber" data-capture="CCAccountNo" CssClass="creditcard" style="width:114px" />
```

If I could just prevent the postback, I believe the entire problem would be solved. I'm already doing e.preventDefault(), but it has no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the card reader send a CRLF at the end of the ASCII stream?

Comment: Can you post the html of the textbox? You've tagged `asp.net` you may have created a server-side event which will cause a postback

Comment: I added the textbox code to the original post.

Comment: Steve: Yes! I believe there is a CRLF at the end of the stream! I didn't realize it, because this doesn't cause a postback on my other page, with all the same code. What can I do to prevent the postback?